# Is spearman correlation a good approach to discriminate anti-phase v/s in-phase?

Tags: python, spearman-rho

I have oscillating time series and i want to discriminate if there are in anti-phase or in in-phase.

At least for cosine like time series it work great. 
Spearman correlation between cosine and -cosine = -1 (complete out-of-phase) and between cosine and sin = 0 (just in the middle between in and antiphase)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
t      = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
x      = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
x_anti = - np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
y      = np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)
ss.spearmanr(x, x_anti)[0]
ss.spearmanr(x, y)[0]
```

I was wondering what are the limitations and if there's a better tool to discriminate it.